# What is the equivalent of System.setProperty (java) in Google Application Engine (in java again)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I got an exception at `System.setProperty` in Java when I've tried to deploy the application in GAE. Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: What property are you trying to set and what does the exception say?

Comment: Yole: I am trying to set the path for WordNet dictionary. The exception is a WordNet exception which is thrown when a WordNet function is unable to find the dictionary.        I tried setting the path with the help of VM argument but now I am getting  ...... access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/WEB-INF/WordNet-3.0/dict/index.sense" "read")    exception which is usually thrown when the system is not able to find the file, although the file is there in the path

Comment: Eduardo - The question is mine again. I posted 2 questions as I thought people might answer one or the other, this one being more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set Java system properties or environment variables for App Engine applications in the respective appengine-web.xml configuration file.

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="property1" value="value1" />
    <property name="property2" value="value2" />
</system-properties>
```

You can find more details in App Engine [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_System_properties_and_environment_variables).